# QtCreator debugger: step into std::function

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator, std-function

I am unable to find any tools within QtCreator that would allow me to debug `std::function` calls and determine what's happening inside.
Is it possible to "step into" `std::function`?

In case it is possible, how do I set it up, because a strait-forward approach (i.e push "step into" button when paused on the corresponding `std::function` execution call) does not work.

Comment: Which OS/compiler/std library?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `"does not work"`.

Comment: @G.M. It does not redirect to the body of the method that is bound to `std::function`. As far as I understand a behavior of the debugger, when it is unable to show the direct code (via symbols), it shows you a corresponding assembly. In my case, it just does nothing. When I "step" onto the `std::function` call and then push "step into", it should jump into the body of the method that `std::function` calls, but it is not doing anything. It works just fine with "non-std::function" calls.

Comment: @rubenvb I am using 4.6.1 on MacOS 10.13.5.

Comment: I'm guessing the actual debugger being used is [`lldb`](https://lldb.llvm.org/)?  If so you might need to use the `si` (`"Instruction level single step"`) command rather than just `s` (`"Source level single step"`) at the `lldb` prompt (or whatever button that corresponds to on your GUI/IDE).

Comment: @G.M. Yea, the actual backend is LLDB.