# How to configure LLDB to skip std::function implementation details?

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

How can I configure LLDB to skip libstdc++ code and jump directly into a function stored inside std::function?

There is a similar question with an answer for gdb:
[How to step into std::function user code from C++ functional with GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429401/how-to-step-into-stdfunction-user-code-from-c-functional-with-gdb)
It works. However LLDB works faster on my machine, so I wonder if it can be configured in a similar way with .lldbinit?

Comment: I compiled the code from other question. From the `f(1)` line, running `step` directly led to the stored function (`myfunc`), no steps through `std::function` or any other parts of libstdc++.

Comment: @DaveLee what lldb version/ which platform do you use? Can you share your config?

Comment: Support for stepping through std::function to its target was added to lldb quite recently. IIRC, it first showed up in Xcode 11.  Try updating your lldb and if that still doesn't work please file a bug.  This is new support, so there might be some case that isn't covered yet.  When it works it works without user intervention.

Comment: Yes, I tested on macOS with lldb-1100.0.30.12 (from Xcode 11.3.1).

Comment: @JimIngham Afaik on MacOs they don't use libstdc++, and have other implementation. Will it work on Linux?

Comment: No, there's only support for the clang std implementation at present.  The design allows lldb to support multiple versions of the std library, so that's not a problem.  OTOH, it was a little tricky to figure out how to make the current support work in a performant manner, so it will take somebody with a good knowledge of libstdc++ to get this to work for that.